# how to get oracle init file pl sql like the spfile

Tags: oracle, filepath, init, database-administration

Hi,

I need to know the location of the oracle init file because i need to do a backup procedure  from the plsql terminal, i need to take it from oracle like the spfile.

```
select value 
INTO   inicialOracle 
from   v$parameter 
where  name = 'spfile';

RESULT
------
C:\ORACLEXE\APP\ORACLE\PRODUCT\11.2.0\SERVER\DBS\SPFILEXE.ORA`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pfile will be present in $ORACLE_HOME\database directory and you will get your SID attached to file as follows `init<sid>.ora`

The problem with just copying the init file is, if changes were made to the spfile and a new init file wasn't created, then these changes won't be reflected in the init file. So it would be better to create an init file before taking a backup.

You can create a pfile from spfile like, (Assuming that you have the necessary privileges)

```
create spfile from pfile; --this will create the file in $ORACLE_HOME\database directory.
create spfile from pfile='location' ;
```